# Data Ownership between super class and sub class

Tags: java, oop

When a subclass inherit a super class , what's the relationship between subclass and the fields with different accessibility defined in super class ,which field is owned by the subclass and which not.
And can someone explain the example below:

```
class Parent
{
  private int partOne = 0;
  public int partTwo = 1;

  public void tellMe()
  {
     System.out.println(partOne);
     System.out.println(partTwo);
  }
}
class Child extends Parent
{
  private int partOne = 2;
  public int partTwo = 3;

  public void main(String[] args)
  {
   Child child = new Child();
   child.tellMe();
  }
}
```

When I debugged  it in Eclipse , I watched the variable *child* in the stack , I found the Child instance has four fields , two defined by its class and two by its parent class , I was very confused.Did I create a parent instance when I create a child instance , IMP , I think it only enter the parent class's constructor, but I can't explain why the child class don't override the two fields , or at least , I think it should override the *partTwo* with the *public* accessibility .Please tell me what is the reason, thanks.

Comment: Arguably fields should always be private for proper [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)).

Comment: @Lucero Here , I just want to give an example about the override.

Answer (score 4):

> why the child class don't override the two fields , or at least , I think it should override the partTwo with the public accessibility

In Java, data members are not polymorphic. This means that in your example, the two fields defined in the `Child` class are completely unrelated to the two fields in the `Parent` class, even though they happen to share their names.

Although this is allowed by the language, doing things of this nature is just a recipe for confusion (as you've discovered).

If you want polymorphic behaviour, create two member *functions*, `getPartOne()` and `getPartTwo()`, and override them as appropriate.

Comment: I don't mean the polymorphic , I just want to make sure who own the two fields defined by the parent class , if not by the child class, who own them ?

Comment: To the extent that "ownership" is a thing that makes any sense, the fields are "owned" by the parent class.

Comment: If they are owned by the parent class , why can the child access them , do I create a parent instance when I create a child instance , if this , it will be a huge waste , but if not this , how can you explain it?

Comment: @ohyeahchenzai, I think that you may be misunderstanding what class inheritance is. It's not a "gives birth to" type of relationship as in humans! It's a "has everything that the super has" type inheritance, which allows you to add and modify functionality in child classes, but never to remove or skip things present on the super.

Comment: @LUCERO I agree with your opinion,but what I really mean is that : When I allocate a child instance , why the fields defined in parent class also hold space , and as it hold space for child class,  why the child instance can't directly own it and manipulate it , and child instance can manipulate it only by the method defined by its parent class.

Comment: @ohyeahchenzai, there is no parent and child instance - they are one instance, combining the fields and methods of the `Child` class, which includes (by inheritance) all the fields and methods that the `Parent` class has. But it's only one instance.

Comment: If the fields inherited from the parent class is contained into the child instance , does the child instance really own it? or does it contains the two fields more like a composing object really does?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you're hiding the access to the field `partTwo` of the `Parent` class by redefining it with the same name on the `Child` class. You should actually get a warning from the compiler about that.

Do the following experiment to see what's happening:

- Add a proper constructor to both classes, calling `super` on the `Child`'s constructor (yes, that's not necessary, but it can help make things clearer).
- Initialize your fields in the constructor instead of directly doing that in the field declaration.
- So far the code will do the same.
- Now remove the `partTwo` variable from the `Child` class - it will still compile but this time the value set by the constructor of `Child` will be applied (and the warning will disappear).

You may have seen the comment I posted about encapsulation - having only private fields prevent such confusion and allows for better maintenance of your classes later on, because you can change the fields of a class without affecting inheriting classes (as long as the methods to access the data remain unchanged).

Comment: I know what you mean , but here I don't mean that meaning , I just want to make sure who own the two fields defined by the parent class?If the child class owned the two , why can't I manipulate them , if owned by the parent class,then?

Comment: @ohyeahchenzai, fields are always "owned" by the class defining them. You can manipulate the public (or protected) fields of the super class if you don't hide them by re-defining fields with the same name (which forces the compiler to pick the "closest" one).

Comment: I got your first sentence , but can you explain the question I post above at Louis.